# Adding constructor (or function) to enum

Tags: c#, enums

I am not sure if a constructor is exactly what I am looking for but if I explain what I am trying to do hopefully someone can tell me if I am trying to do is a silly idea or whether there are ways to do it.

So I have an enum:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Normal, 
    Error, 
    Chat, 
    Groupchat, 
    Headline
}
```

This enum is basically a wrapper for the jabber.net `MessageType`. So I want to create my enum from this. So at the moment I have a function like this:

```
private MessageType ConvertMessageType(JabberMessageType jabberType)
{
    MessageType type = MessageType.Error;

    switch (jabberType)
    {
        case JabberMessageType.normal:
            type = MessageType.Normal;
            break;

        //etc
    }

    return type;
}
```

So I have to use `enum MessageType type = ConvertMessageType(JabberMessageType.groupchat);`

What I would like though is to be able to do something like:

```
enum MessageType type = MessageType(JabberMessageType.groupchat);
// or 
enum MessageType type = MessageType.FromJabberJid(JabberMessageType.groupchat);
```

So that the conversion belongs with the enum rather than being a method outtside of.

Comment: If the underlying ints mean the same then you can assign directly like `JabberMessageType.normal` 0 equals `MessageType.Normal`( 0) and further ....`MessageType type = (MessageType type) jabberType`

Comment: Do the values correlate to one another across the enums? If so, you need not "convert" but just cast.

Comment: In Java you can do this, both defining a constructor and with a non static method. Here your only option is to create an extension.

Comment: Casting is of course possible however I wouldn't like to do this as it is not certain that values will remain the same and in future instances it might be that they aren't. It is also that I was just interested in what is actually possible in C#

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to do this for you?

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static MessageType ConvertMessageType(this JabberMessageType jabberType)
    {
        switch(jabberType)
        {
            case JabberMessageType.normal:
                return MessageType.Normal;
            // Add rest of types here.
            default:
                return MessageType.Error;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var type = JabberMessageType.normal; // JabberMessageType
var messageType = type.ConvertMessageType(); // Converted to your custom MessageType
```

Comment: The switch statement wouldn't be necessary if JabberMessageType was an enum and you could ensure the enum values were the same (e.g. JabberMessageType.normal is 1, and so is MessageType.Normal). Then the ConvertMessageType method would just convert JabberMessageType to int and then cast the int to MessageType.

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. The more I use C# the more I actually like it as a language. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this. An [Enumeration Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) translates to an `int` (or `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `uint`, `long` or `ulong` if specified) value and is not technically a `class`.

> An enumeration type (also named an enumeration or an enum) provides an
>   efficient way to define a set of named integral constants that may be
>   assigned to a variable.

One solution would be to put a static method to do this in a `Utilities` class.

```
MessageType type = Utilities.MessageTypeFromJabberJid(JabberMessageType.groupchat);
```

Comment: Doesn't _strictly_ map to an integer - by default yes, but other value types are valid, also.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Ah, interesting, I wasn't aware of this. How? just doing = 0.5 gives me an error saying it can't convert to an int?

Comment: @ConnellWatkins "By default the underlying type of each element in the enum is int. You can specify another integral numeric type by using a colon, as shown in the previous example. " i.e: `public enum MessageType : byte { }` Please note it's integral numeric types only though. So no 0.5s etc

Comment: @J.Kommer thanks! I did actually know you could do this. It's only with integer-like types though, I thought @Mr.Disappointment meant things like `decimal`, `bool`, `DateTime`, etc. I've updated my answer to briefly include this.

Answer (score 1):

How about a class where your enum is nested?
Something like this

```
public static class Message
{
    public enum Types
    {

    }

    public static Message.Types ConvertMessageType(Message.Types jabberType)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple one-liner which require less tweaking in future (in case further enum values are added), but this assumes, the enum names are the same in both types:

```
private MessageType ToMessageType(this JabberMessageType jabberType)
{
    return Enum.Parse(typeof(MessageType), jabberType.ToString(), true);
}
```

This is some kind of a mapping functionality, from one type to another.